# Can anyone please tell which is the best software in ubuntu to plot graph against data?

Tags: 12.04, plot

Can anyone please let me know which is the best software in ubuntu to plot graph against data??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to make perfect graphs (and don't mind spending some time on them) I'd recommend using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) (a python library) which has good mix of depth and simplicity. Otherwise, just use [LibreOffice's Calc](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/calc/) for quick graphing.

Comment: @karel I think John is talking about the learning curve that takes some time.

Comment: @user1693801 Hi. On Ask Ubuntu you don't need to say thanks. You can just upvote (the little up arrow on the left of the question). That will give John some reputation.

Comment: @don.joey Hi,i appreciate your concern, but i just created my account,and to vote up i need to have have some reputation. I'm lacking that as of now.

Comment: @Ganesh ah Ganesh. I completely forgot about that. Sorry. By accepting the question you also give him some rep so that is good.

Answer (score 2):

A program which in my opinion is far superior to Calc or matplot lib, is [Veusz](http://home.gna.org/veusz/). It has a simple graphical interface, and can produce beautiful plots (allmost all graphs I publish now come from veusz as you can export as PDF and SVG vectored images allow scaling without pixelation, combined with the great quality).

Answer (score 1):

I was using Octave for a while. Is a perfect alternative for Matlab.
http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/

Comment: +1 for octave, but I'm not sure "perfect" is how I'd describe it.

Answer (score 0):

I always use desmos.com. It's an "online graphing calculator".

[image]

it has nothing to do with ubuntu but it's best for your needs!

direct link: https://www.desmos.com/